# Как добавить запись в БД и направить на печать через кнопку?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Добрый день. Я только начинаю изучение AJAX и наткнулся на проблему:
Как связать событие на кнопку чтобы одновременно шла запись в таблицу БД и выводилась на печать?

Answer (score 2):

При нажатие на кнопку отправление формы можно сделать отправку твоих данных на сервер и печать блока :

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url:  $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize()
      })
      .done(function() {
        console.log('success');
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log('fail');
      });
    printDiv("divName"); //id div блока 
    //отмена действия по умолчанию для кнопки submit        
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```